# symfony 2.8 не могу подключить пакет scheb / two-factor-bundle

Tags: symfony2

есть пакет "scheb/two-factor-bundle", первая версия которого для `Symfony2`. прочитал документацию, но не понял в какой контроллер нужно вписать создание урл-а для пользователя: [смотреть раздел QR Codes](https://github.com/scheb/two-factor-bundle/blob/2.x/Resources/doc/google.md)

```
$url = $container->get("scheb_two_factor.security.google_authenticator")->getUrl($user);
```

пробовал подключать версию Этого пакета для `Symfony4` - все получилось, но с версией для `Smf2` - полная непонятка

Answer (score 0):

на этот вопрос ответил создатель пакета 
https://github.com/scheb/two-factor-bundle/issues/273

первая и вторая версии пакета, со слов автора, не поддерживают csrf защиту. автор пакета настоятельно рекомендует использовать последнюю версию пакета